# JPQL SELECT between date statement

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

I would like to convert this SQL statement to a JPQL equivalent.

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE events_date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-03-31';
```

This correctly retrieves the information from the table `events`.

In my `Events` entity

```
   @Column(name = "events_date")  
   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)  
   private Date eventsDate;
```

So far this is what I have but it is not working.

```
public List<Events> findAllEvents(Date startDate, Date endDate) {    
  List<Events> allEvents = entityManager.createQuery(
    "SELECT e FROM Events e WHERE t.eventsDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")  
  .setParameter("startDate", startDate, TemporalType.DATE)  
  .setParameter("endDate", endDate, TemporalType.DATE)  
  .getResultList();
  return allEvents ;  
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try this query (replace `t.eventsDate` with `e.eventsDate`):

```
SELECT e FROM Events e WHERE e.eventsDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<Student> findStudentByReports(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    System.out.println("call findStudentMethd******************with this pattern"
                    + startDate
                    + endDate
                    + "*********************************************");

    return em
            .createQuery(
                    "' select attendence from Attendence attendence where attendence.admissionDate BETWEEN : startDate '' AND endDate ''"
                            + "'")
            .setParameter("startDate", startDate, TemporalType.DATE)
            .setParameter("endDate", endDate, TemporalType.DATE)
            .getResultList();

}
```

Comment: I don't get how this query is different from the query in the question. Also, shouldn't there be <code>:</code> before endDate? And why are are there 2 single quotes after startDate, and after end endDate?