# JPA 2.0 Date Comparsin JPA query

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I am trying to execute following query, but its throwing error.

```
SELECT t from Table t where t.status = :status and t.ndate > (t.ndate - 12/24) AND t.ndate < (t.ndate + 12/24)
```

Error

```
ERROR: Filter invalid. Cannot compare field ndate of type java.util.Date to value of type long. Numeric comparisons must be between numeric types only
```

Do we any other way to do this?

Comment: consider using `FORMAT` to format your dates as long "ddmmyyyy" for ex

Answer (score 0):

`(t.ndate - 12/24)` returns a numeric value not a date and that can not be compared with the `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Use a native query with function `Date_add` r you have to do the calculation in java

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to query if the `t.ndate` is between two fixed dates.
Then you can calculate the date you want in Java and use these computed date values (in the example, `:start` and `:end`) in the query. This way you can use normal comparison and avoid introducing dependencies on a native query language.
You better should use the comparison with BETWEEN in this case, as it is more readable:

```
t.ndate BETWEEN :start AND :end
```

See also [JPQL SELECT between date statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350994/jpql-select-between-date-statement) and especially
[Java: JPQL date function to add a time period to another date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856386/java-jpql-date-function-to-add-a-time-period-to-another-date).