# How to do between or between query with Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

how I can do a query with Criteria API with between or between for this plain sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM
  documents
WHERE (register_date BETWEEN to_date('02.07.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY') AND to_date('02.07.2018', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
OR (sign_date BETWEEN to_date('02.07.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY') AND to_date('02.07.2018', 'DD.MM.YYYY'));
```

in postgres?

It's not a dublicate because I'm doing a query with TWO between and a question in the link below hasn't criteria api as I can see

I need to make something like this

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.getCSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Documents> documentsCriteria = cb.createQuery(model_class);

Root<Documents> DocumentsRoot = documentsCriteria.from(model_class);
documentsCriteria.select(DocumentsRoot);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

if (register_start_date != null && register_end_date != null) {
    predicates.add(cb.between(DocumentsRoot.get("register_date"), register_start_date, register_end_date));
    predicates.add(cb.between(DocumentsRoot.get("sign_date"), register_start_date, register_end_date));
}

documentsCriteria.where(cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));

List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
orderList.add(cb.asc(DocumentsRoot.get("register_date")));
orderList.add(cb.asc(DocumentsRoot.get("sign_date")));

documentsCriteria.orderBy(orderList);

Query q = this.getCSession().createQuery(documentsCriteria);

return (List<Documents>) q.getResultList();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPQL SELECT between date statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350994/jpql-select-between-date-statement)

Comment: Would be great if you can show your attempt. There are lot of similar questions floating around such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806152/add-criteriabuilder-betweendate-to-predicate).

Answer (score 4):

you create the criteria based on the entity manager and then you add the between restriction to it.

```
Criteria criteria = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(EntityDao.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("your_date_column", date1, date2));
```

between or between

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.between("your_date_column", date1, date2), Restrictions.between("your_date_column", date3, date4)));
```

Comment: Ok, for one between It's ok! how to make between or between?!

Comment: you add multiple between restrictions to it

Comment: If I create next between It will be between AND between, but I need between OR between

Comment: criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.between("your_date_column", new Date(), new Date()), 
                Restrictions.between("your_date_column", new Date(), new Date())));

Comment: I need to put something like this in my documentsCriteria.where

If I will make
            predicates.add(cb.or(cb.between(DocumentsRoot.get("register_date"), register_start_date, register_end_date), cb.between(DocumentsRoot.get("sign_date"), register_start_date, register_end_date)));
than the count of the rows is not a same compare with a plain sql

Comment: might you get away with a java statement?

Comment: OK, it works correct, It's my mistake, Thanks everyone!

Comment: you should approve it then